# magento 2: Products not adding to minicart but showing in /checkout/cart via ajax call api

Tags: magento2

I have integrated a 3rd party service api chatbot- basically to assist users online via chat, where the users can request for trending products, today's deals etc.

I have a situation: When i add product to shopping cart via the 'chat bot service api', the products does not show up in the minicart (even after refresh, clearing cache and running content deploy command), but when i navigate to /checkout/cart, there the products shows up.

**Only if I logout and login for the same user, then the products can be seen in the minicart, for the current session it is not showing**

But with normal magento - adding products to shopping cart, there products are adding to minicart.

Can anyone pls suggest how to proceed.

Im not using any custom module for this chatbot, its only an api call.

**So far debug done on:**

> Tried to move the !_.isEmpty(storageInvalidation.keys()) condition outside else as suggested here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5946
>
> Not sure if i have to change all this as suggested here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/eec3cf17bc5deae71c83c797d1339de46cf6905f#diff-a64661f242d03f8ebbcfdcf080d29e7c

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand using the API is updating the system via REST endpoint, thus is will not update knockout.js V(iew) M(Module). This will require you to refresh the page which is completely normal. You would have to update the chat bot to integrate into Magento2 frontend javascript system (knockout.js) for your desired results.
-Hope this helps,
    Chris